# How to extract numbers from numeric object

Tags: r

For example, for numbers `412,34523,123412` I would extract 4,3 and 1. I guess I can turn them into characters, sliced them and then pick the first. Is there any better way?

Comment: Which 4's do you want to extract? How many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
s=c(412,34523,123412)
 substring(s,1,1)
[1] "4" "3" "1"
```